# same height images with flexbox

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to have same size images with flexbox. I give a `display: flex;` to my `slick-track` container and then `flex: 1 0 auto` to my `img`. I thought that with a `flex-grow` of `1` my image will increase if they are too small but it didn't happen.

[the codepen here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KaoLPq)

```js
$(".image-carousel").slick({
    // autoplay: true,
    dots: true,
 slidesToShow:3,
 
});
```

```css
.slick-track {
  display: flex;
}
.slick-track .slick-slide img {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-carousel">
  <div class="slick-slide">
    <figure class="slick-slide-inner">
      <img class="slick-slide-image" src="http://parnasse.ovh/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/gene-300x168.jpg" alt="noo">
      <figcaption class="elementor-image-carousel-caption">gene</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </div>
  <div class="slick-slide">
    <figure class="slick-slide-inner">
      <img class="slick-slide-image" src="http://parnasse.ovh/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/chimie-300x225.jpeg" alt="chimie">
      <figcaption class="elementor-image-carousel-caption">chimie</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </div>
  <div class="slick-slide ">
    <figure class="slick-slide-inner">
      <img class="slick-slide-image" src="http://parnasse.ovh/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/cerveau-300x180.jpg" alt="cerveau">
      <figcaption class="elementor-image-carousel-caption">cerveau</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </div>
  <div class="slick-slide">
    <figure class="slick-slide-inner">
      <img class="slick-slide-image" src="http://parnasse.ovh/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/cropped-Science-300x300.jpg" alt="mpo">
      <figcaption class="elementor-image-carousel-caption">cropped-Science.jpg</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </div>
  <div class="slick-slide">
    <figure class="slick-slide-inner">
      <img class="slick-slide-image" src="http://parnasse.ovh/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/ordi-300x169.jpg" alt="pôo">
      <figcaption class="elementor-image-carousel-caption">ordi</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </div>
  <div class="slick-slide ">
    <figure class="slick-slide-inner">
      <img class="slick-slide-image" src="http://parnasse.ovh/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/astro-300x188.jpg" alt="captiopn 1">
      <figcaption class="elementor-image-carousel-caption">astro</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </div>
  <div class="slick-slide">
    <figure class="slick-slide-inner">
      <img class="slick-slide-image" src="http://parnasse.ovh/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/Einstein-300x169.jpg" alt="roo">
      <figcaption class="elementor-image-carousel-caption">Einstein</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </div>
  <div class="slick-slide">
    <figure class="slick-slide-inner">
      <img class="slick-slide-image" src="http://parnasse.ovh/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/gene-300x168.jpg" alt="noo">
      <figcaption class="elementor-image-carousel-caption">gene</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </div>
  <div class="slick-slide">
    <img class="slick-slide-image" src="http://parnasse.ovh/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/chimie-300x225.jpeg" alt="chimie">
    <figcaption class="elementor-image-carousel-caption">chimie</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </div>
  <div class="slick-slide">
    <figure class="slick-slide-inner">
      <img class="slick-slide-image" src="http://parnasse.ovh/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/cerveau-300x180.jpg" alt="cerveau">
      <figcaption class="elementor-image-carousel-caption">cerveau</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </div>
  <div class="slick-slide">
    <figure class="slick-slide-inner">
      <img class="slick-slide-image" src="http://parnasse.ovh/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/cropped-Science-300x300.jpg" alt="mpo">
      <figcaption class="elementor-image-carousel-caption">cropped-Science.jpg</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </div>
  <div class="slick-slide">
    <figure class="slick-slide-inner">
      <img class="slick-slide-image" src="http://parnasse.ovh/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/ordi-300x169.jpg" alt="pôo">
      <figcaption class="elementor-image-carousel-caption">ordi</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </div>
  <div class="slick-slide">
    <figure class="slick-slide-inner">
      <img class="slick-slide-image" src="http://parnasse.ovh/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/astro-300x188.jpg" alt="captiopn 1">
      <figcaption class="elementor-image-carousel-caption">astro</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep in mind that flex properties only work between parent and child.

You have `display: flex` on `.slick-track`. This means that the flex equal height feature (`align-items: stretch`) will apply to the child elements (`.slick-slide`).

And these child elements (flex items) are indeed equal height – once you remove the `height: 100%` on them, which overrides the equal height feature.

[**revised codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jyzjGJ)

Your `img` elements are descendants of the flex container, but not children, so they don't recognize flex properties. You'll need to make each parent a flex container for the images to be full-height.

[**revised codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MJVMVg)

Answer (score 2):

Here's another option, maintaining proportion and centering each image within the slide. This is probably as good as it gets unless you use `background-image`, which is more flexible when it comes to fitting inside of a container.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pRLXxz

Comment: `background-image` is the way to go, way more flexibility than `img` tags.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to limit the width of the slider (the main container) so the slides, I mean the pictures, don't be so huge.

Then move the params you gave to the img to its parent element.

```
.slick-track {
    display: flex;
}
.slick-slide {
    flex: 1 0 auto;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.slick-slide img {
    width: 100%;
}
.elementor-image-carousel-caption {
    text-align: center; /* just for aesthetics */
}
```

Hope it helps.